# Uncaught ApolloError: Error message not found

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

I have onError Link function.

```
const logUserOut = () => {
      if (getCurrentUser()) {
        logout();
        navigate?.('/login');
      }
    };
    const error = graphQLErrors?.[0];
    // @ts-ignore
    const { code } = error || {};
    if (error?.extensions?.code === 'UNAUTHENTICATED' || code === 401 || code === 403) {
      logger.info('User logged out due to authentication error', error);
      logUserOut();
    } else if (networkError?.message === 'Failed to fetch') {
      logUserOut();
    }
    LogRocket.error(error || networkError);
```

what is the reason for the error mention above?

search online

Comment: Not sure if it is the same for you, but I got exactly the same error when aborting requests.